# implement a loggin function or macro can log date and function name

Tags: c++, c++11, macros

I want to write a logging function or macro which can accept other callback functions as parameter and run the callback function inside, log runtime and name.
But callback function may have different parameter type and number,and i don't want to pass callback function'name as parameter explicitly.

i try to use std::bind and std::function

> ```
> void log(std::function<void()> callbackFunc){
>         //assuming all callbackFunc return type is void
>         struct timeval tmBegin, tmEnd;
>         gettimeofday(&tmBegin);
>         callbackFunc();
>         gettimeofday(&tmEnd);
>         //then write tmEnd - tmBegin to file
>         //but i dont know how to get callbackFunc's name}
>
> void callbackFunc1(int);
> void callbackFunc2(int ,char, string);
> log(std::bind(callbackFunc1, 1));
> log(std::bind(callbackFunc2, 2, 'c', "test"));
> ```

Aside,maybe callback function has different return type, is possible to implement a log function like this?

Comment: Have you looked at variadic templates (since C++11), for example at http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/variadic-templates-in-c/

Comment: This is so not `C`...removing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The names of functions (and variables, etc, etc) are lost when compiling. The compiler doesn't (really) know the name of a function. You can use `__FUNCTION__` to get the name of the function you are in, but not useful in this case. You could perhaps do something with a macro that replaces `bind`, or the simple solution is to just pass in a string along with the function as an argument to `log`.

The macro solution is more complex, as you have to deal with variable arguments, but something like this would work):

```
#define LOG(f, ...) log(std::bind(f, __VA_ARGS__), #f)
```

and modify `log` to:

```
void log(std::function<void()> callbackFunc, const char* name)
```

Edit: Different return types could be dealt with by making `log` a templated function, and using the template as the type argument in the `std::function` return type:

```
template<typename RET>
void log(std::function<RET()> callbackFunc)
```

(I haven't tested this, but I believe it will work)

Comment: How did this happen? we have nearly the same answer, at the exact same time :-)

Comment: thanks, it works. by the way, if callback funcion has different return type, how to pass in and handle return

Comment: @Amit: Happens from time to time - choosing obvious names for variables, etc, would have something to do with it being very similar.

Comment: `std::function<void()>` can accept callable which return non `void`, so first solution is ok. Moreover, with the template function, we have to pass a `std::function` or explicitly provide `RET`, as `RET` cannot be deduced for some callable (as lambda).

Comment: @MatsPetersson template function return type can not be deduced, call log(callbackFunc, 1)error

Comment: @Jarod42 it seems that if log is template, caller must pass in the return type, #define LOG(f, rtype, ...) log<rtype>(std::bind(f, __VA_ARGS__), #f).can make the LOG macro deduce callback function return type?

Comment: @cavehubiao: Do you use `rtype` in your code ? if not `void` return type works also for other `rtype`. if yes, I suggest to use `template<typename F> void log(F f, const char* name)` and then `auto r = f();`

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the log call in a variadic macro (as you "guessed") to grab the parameter itself (function address) as well as it's name:

```
#define log(f, ...) _log(std::bind(f, __VA_ARGS__), #f)

void _log(std::function<void()> callbackFunc, const char *fName){
   // ...
}

log(callbackFunc1, 1);
```